# How to use fluidRow method in shiny using R?

Tags: r, shiny

I have used the fluidrow method for the dashboard but the radioButtons argument is not right so what is the right argument.

```
# Application Layout
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    br(),
   titlePanel("Country Salary"),
    p("Explore the difference between people who earn less than 50K and more than 50K. You can filter the data by country, then explore various demogrphic information."),
    
    # TASK 2: Add first fluidRow to select input for country
    fluidRow(
      column(12, 
             wellPanel(selectInput("country", "Select Country",c("United-States", "Canada", "Mexico", "Germany", "Philippines"))  # add select input 
             )
    ),
    
    # TASK 3: Add second fluidRow to control how to plot the continuous variables
    fluidRow(
      column(3, 
             wellPanel(
               p("Select a continuous variable and graph type (histogram or boxplot) to view on the right."),
               radioButtons( "continuous_variable","Continuos variable",choices ="age" , "hours_per_week"),   # add radio buttons for continuous variables
               radioButtons("graph_type","Graph", choices = "histogram","boxplot")    # add radio buttons for chart type
               )
             ),
      column(9, plotOutput("P1"))  # add plot output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `shinyUI` is superseded, I suggest the use of `shinyApp(ui, server)`.
2. You have a typo in all of your `radioButtons` calls, where your `choices=` should be in a `c(...)` vector. For example, change

   ```
   radioButtons("categorical_variable","Category",choices = "education", "workclass", "sex"),
   ```

   to

   ```
   radioButtons("categorical_variable","Category",choices = c("education", "workclass", "sex")),
   ```
3. You also have a missing close-paren in the first `fluidRow`.

Fixed:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  titlePanel("Country Salary"),
  p("Explore the difference between people who earn less than 50K and more than 50K. You can filter the data by country, then explore various demogrphic information."),

  # TASK 2: Add first fluidRow to select input for country
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           wellPanel(selectInput("country", "Select Country",c("United-States", "Canada", "Mexico", "Germany", "Philippines"))  # add select input
                     )
           )),

  # TASK 3: Add second fluidRow to control how to plot the continuous variables
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             p("Select a continuous variable and graph type (histogram or boxplot) to view on the right."),
             radioButtons( "continuous_variable","Continuos variable",choices = c("age" , "hours_per_week")),   # add radio buttons for continuous variables
             radioButtons("graph_type","Graph", choices = c("histogram","boxplot"))    # add radio buttons for chart type
           )
           ),
    column(9, plotOutput("P1"))  # add plot output
  ),

  # TASK 4: Add third fluidRow to control how to plot the categorical variables
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             p("Select a categorical variable to view bar chart on the right. Use the check box to view a stacked bar chart to combine the income levels into one graph. "),
             radioButtons("categorical_variable","Category",choices = c("education", "workclass", "sex")),    # add radio buttons for categorical variables
             checkboxInput("is_stacked", "Bars stacked")    # add check box input for stacked bar chart option
           )
           ),
    column(9,  plotOutput("p2"))  # add plot output
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: sample shiny app]